# Autodesk Forge: WorkItem failing due to AppPackage Issues

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

My AppPackage fails to load, and I'm unable to find the exact answer in the documentation or by the error message/code.

I tested the bundle by unzipping it into the "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins" on my local machine, and it runs/loads as expected.

The AppPackage indicates that it is created successfully, which I'm sure is the most up-to-date version.

The addin is a .NET DLL file.

Error Report Message

```
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] Starting work item ffbcfc1ca50546fc9a6372424b2cdae1
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] Start download phase.
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] Start downloading file <CENSORED>.
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] Start preparing AppPackage <CENSORED>.
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] Download bits and install app to local cache.
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] End downloading file <CENSORED>.
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] End download phase.
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] Error: Failed to prepare app package(s).
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Downloading of job.
[02/15/2019 18:44:48] Job finished with result FailedEnvironmentSetup
```

PackageContents.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ApplicationPackage SchemaVersion="1.0" AutodeskProduct="AutoCAD"
                    AppVersion="0.1.0"
                    ProductType="Application"
                    Name="CENSORED"
                    Description="CENSORED"
                    Author="CENSORED"
                    FriendlyVersion="0.1.0"
                    ProductCode="{CENSORED}"
                    UpgradeCode="{CENSORED}"
                    Helpfile="./help.html"
                    Icon="./my-icon.jpeg">

    <CompanyDetails Name="CENSORED" Phone="CENSORED" Email="CENSORED"/>

    <Components>
        <RuntimeRequirements SeriesMin="R22.0" Platform="AutoCAD*" OS="Win64"/>

        <ComponentEntry AppName="CENSORED" Version="0.1.0" ModuleName="./CENSORED.dll" AppType=".Net"
                        AppDescription="CENSORED" LoadOnAutoCADStartup="True">
        </ComponentEntry>
    </Components>

</ApplicationPackage>
```

Activity Definition:
Note I had to manually expand some inline functions here, since I have this broken into multiple parts.  If I have a typo, rest assured the code actually runs syntactically.

```
let activity = <CreateActivityRequest>{
            Id: id,
            Version: 1,
            IsPublic: false,
            AppPackages: ['PACKAGE_NAME'],
            Instruction: {Script: 'D6 '},
            RequiredEngineVersion: '22.0',
            Parameters: {
                InputParameters: [{Name: 'HostDwg', LocalFileName: '$(HostDwg)'}],
                OutputParameters: [{Name: 'output', LocalFileName: `output.json`}]
            },
            HostApplication: undefined,
            AllowedChildProcesses: []
        };
```

Entry from AppPackages Listing:

```
{
  References: [],
  Resource: '...',
  RequiredEngineVersion: '22.0',
  IsPublic: false,
  IsObjectEnabler: false,
  Version: 1,
  Timestamp: '2019-02-15T19:32:33.527Z',
  Description: '',
  Id: 'CENSORED'
},
```

Comment: Can you list the .NET references you're using? It should be only `AcDbMgd` and `AcCoreMgd` (from Autodesk)

Comment: Acdbmgd, accoremgd, acmgd.  This addin was built for AutoCAD, so i'll surmise you'll suggest refactoring out just the code I need, so I won't need the acmgd reference.  I'm using the acmgd library to get at the block properties tables' rows.  My understanding is that changing a block property table through the API requires manually updating the related values.  I realize it's internal, but it's the only way I found.  Assuming the acmgd library has to be removed, is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to double check how you zipped the AppPackage you uploaded.  If you look inside your zip file, make sure you have a folder with the name PACKAGE_NAME.bundle and the PackageContents.XML file is inside that PACKAGE_NAME.bundle folder.

Comment: I tried to find the documentation on what to provide to the app store, but maybe I failed to dig deeper.  You were correct - I needed a .bundle folder inside my zip file; not just a zip file with the contents.

Comment: if you're using `v3`, you can check this tutorial: http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels