# Error while executing Work Item "Cannot find the addin file"

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit, autodesk-designautomation

I am new to the Design Automation API, so please excuse and correct me if I am using the wrong terms. I am setting up the wiring for my very first Design Automation AppBundle, and I have almost all of it working. I followed the patterns in the "Delete Walls" tutorial.
I have a working add-in DLL that I can test locally and it runs under the "design.automation-csharp-revit.local.debug.tool".
I also have all of the Rest API connections setup, and I can successfully submit a WorkItem that will download a Revit file from a BIM 360, and start processing it in the sandbox of Design Automation. But I am getting an error during the execution on the sandbox where it seems it can't find my add-in file. Here is an excerpt from the WorkItem log:

```
[07/21/2020 18:02:26] Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
[07/21/2020 18:02:26] Running user application....
[07/21/2020 18:02:31] Cannot find the addin file: 
[07/21/2020 18:02:31] Fail to deploy Addon DLL(s) in AppPackages.
[07/21/2020 18:02:31] RESULT: Failure
```

I have looked through "bundle" ZIP file many times looking for typos that could cause this, but I can't find anything, it looks identical to the "delete walls" example. So I'm wondering if there is somewhere else that I need to look. Or any other way I could debug this to find out were the connection is missing. I can only assume that the AppBundle and Activity items are setup correctly since I am getting this far and the error is not mentioning either of those items.

Any tips on where to look?

Comment: Could you share the non-confidential AppBundle to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com; It would be quick If we can look into the ZIP package to see if any bad smell inside. Thanks

Comment: @EasonKang e-mail sent.

Comment: seems not able to catch your email in our case system. Did the mail send to forge.help@autodesk.com?

Comment: @BretThompson Meanwhile also look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54716670/11057988). This typically is the issue at times. If you can post a snapshot of the zipped folder in your question, that will be great.

Comment: @RahulBhobe, Thank you for the link, this helped to locate the issue, and unfortunately it was a misspelling on my part that I finally located.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a misspelling of the [dot]bundle folder extension that triggered the issue.