# Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -19088744 which indicates an error

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I am working on a Revit Design Automation app. I am following the instructions that are presented with the tutorial. When I submit my work item the job jails with 'failedInstructions' error.

Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -19088744 which indicates an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the full report:

```
[07/28/2020 06:34:10] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "[$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i $(args[rvtFile].path) /al $(appbundles[AppliedVR4].path)]"
]
"Settings":{
  "dasreportfaileduploadoptional": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"e72a71b50f194cc89fb4dd4fda928c67"
"ActivityId":"AppliedVR4.AppliedVR4Activity2+test"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Revit!35"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"AppliedVR4.AppliedVR4!31"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "rvtFile": {
    "localName": "input.rvt",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:+lo4+1yZ0UHG78KXi8qaxkGWDuw="
  },
  "result": {
    "localName": "result.avr",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:D9DBQayMQvFwzTKzcVtWoD1ON8U=",
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"4FyUuuVl4pVvukCOYHLNiPVnAaz7uJfk\"},\"scope\":\"code:all data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete\",\"expires_in\":3578,\"client_id\":\"4FyUuuVl4pVvukCOYHLNiPVnAaz7uJfk\"}"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
}
[07/28/2020 06:34:10] Starting work item e72a71b50f194cc89fb4dd4fda928c67
[07/28/2020 06:34:10] Start download phase.
[07/28/2020 06:34:10] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/49f68e94-a25e-4606-8675-a7a088adfefa?region=US'
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] '17813504' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\e72a71b50f194cc89fb4dd4fda928c67\input.rvt.
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] End downloading file 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/49f68e94-a25e-4606-8675-a7a088adfefa?region=US'.
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] End download phase successfully.
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] Command line: [ /i T:\Aces\Jobs\e72a71b50f194cc89fb4dd4fda928c67\input.rvt /al T:\Aces\Applications\5fc5cf84be5cde0ff6e5d6c44c1d0505.AppliedVR4.AppliedVR4[31].package]]
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] Identified standalone application at [T:\Aces\AcesRoot\20.0\coreEngine\Exe\\revitcoreconsole.exe.
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] Start script phase.
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] ### Command line arguments: /isolate HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_e72a71b50f194cc89fb4dd4fda928c67 "T:\Aces\Jobs\e72a71b50f194cc89fb4dd4fda928c67\userdata" /exe "[T:\Aces\AcesRoot\20.0\coreEngine\Exe\\revitcoreconsole.exe"  /i T:\Aces\Jobs\e72a71b50f194cc89fb4dd4fda928c67\input.rvt /al T:\Aces\Applications\5fc5cf84be5cde0ff6e5d6c44c1d0505.AppliedVR4.AppliedVR4[31].package].
[07/28/2020 06:34:11] Start application revitcoreconsole.exe standard output dump.
[07/28/2020 06:34:12] End application revitcoreconsole.exe standard output dump.
[07/28/2020 06:34:12] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -19088744 which indicates an error.
[07/28/2020 06:34:12] End script phase.
[07/28/2020 06:34:12] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[07/28/2020 06:34:12] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[07/28/2020 06:34:12] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/AppliedVR4/e72a71b50f194cc89fb4dd4fda928c67/report.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGVJZKM3PIAYPVMQ&Expires=1595932450&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEC8aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDVcCLPyau%2Fbcq8MGD%2BLTdbN3mnKZXRQ5EOrW1k%2B%2BaLjgIgAIxbRh3l40SoodftgUv6j62hzfyuXPn6S5ElUAb%2Fck4q3gEI5%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDH%2F%2Bdc0eHW5n78VW4yqyAbcOas%2F0JxYHwV2HJzN5mtilja0P0vCveCfxRPo2mTE%2BoIpt%2Fu6X8KJPesmZEyb80lDmwh23slylXMKeDr2Sgd92psGERJWxNRy1crMXuO3l6nZ8QHE1UrA%2BPZJmcThaPiop9PkjEBdIHvzgInq1L%2Fhi0364EG2njpdYs%2FLbettxserXm5sJGw5BjFWoIzO9Vr9Sv8hN6tq%2FWaDEWZgTfjgpWY93im5jzHANVHJNTug8I%2BEwpYH%2F%2BAU64AEaJmd6uLAuGMu3xv8v3l8bo38Vzg9yjYlswcT9z482TDE4%2FrAakmfOh7P6wPOqA5Tw8sW020H6ojghuUTXWufsLm7FcJxTLQyKqYIThW79rkAyRUdPoaqf5SObhmxAhFmmdn%2BWqidzpz%2B6Y5w97C9sH5HRWrlPG89Ygq2StAADPZvy%2FFhpH1Fqayk4UtV74%2FRuwX0T32GT50AjdgkHUgz%2ByNVcBGtti5%2B%2B4i%2FKbHUecWK%2BTKpDhR16ctCkOr%2FIehf2rcaVzgYTxfTRbSsdvKLkm%2F%2F1pY%2BJFLwQo0EzQ7ltlw%3D%3D&Signature=U8uySOmxvoFgNdu32AoF2DuEmRk%3D",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2020-07-28T06:34:09.8535659Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2020-07-28T06:34:10.0948438Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2020-07-28T06:34:11.1278192Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2020-07-28T06:34:12.3083113Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 17813504
  },
  "id": "e72a71b50f194cc89fb4dd4fda928c67"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not provide much info on why your workitem might have failed. I'd start with adding some debug logs into the code as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395427/11057988)

Comment: I would suggest testing the addin locally first, using this [tool](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-csharp-revit.local.debug.tool). Let us know if the app keeps failing on Cloud

Comment: We can run and debug the Forge plugin locally and it works as expected. We also added some logging, but it doesn't seem like OnStartUp is getting called at all. Also, we used to be able to run the plugin on Forge without an issue, not sure if there has been an internal change on the Forge side causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> We can run and debug the Forge plugin locally and it works as expected. We also added some logging, but it doesn't seem like OnStartUp is getting called at all. Also, we used to be able to run the plugin on Forge without an issue, not sure if there has been an internal change on the Forge side causing this issue

I’d start with why `OnStartup` is not getting called. Among the possibilities:

- There is a typo in the comment (and I am guessing the code is correct). But confirm that the function name is [`OnStartup()`](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-sketchit-revit/blob/c3b6c41e4e5d2d419b87d94b6c817c535ba220f1/SketchIt/Revit.Addin/SketchItApp/SketchIt.cs#L15).
- Confirm that the [`<FullClassName>`](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-sketchit-revit/blob/c3b6c41e4e5d2d419b87d94b6c817c535ba220f1/SketchIt/Revit.Addin/SketchItApp/SketchIt.cs#L15) tag provided in the bundled addin file resolves correctly in the [assembly code](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-sketchit-revit/blob/c3b6c41e4e5d2d419b87d94b6c817c535ba220f1/SketchIt/Revit.Addin/SketchItApp/SketchIt.cs#L13).
- Confirm that the [`<Assembly>`](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-sketchit-revit/blob/c3b6c41e4e5d2d419b87d94b6c817c535ba220f1/SketchIt/Revit.Addin/SketchItApp/SketchIt.bundle/Contents/SketchIt.addin#L5) tag provided in the assembly file corresponds to relative path to the valid assembly dll.
- Make sure all the dependencies of the assembly dll are also bundled
  in the app bundle.

See a sample [appbundle](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-sketchit-revit/raw/master/SketchIt/Revit.Addin/SketchItApp/bundles/SketchIt.zip). And also see some common solutions around such problems in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54716670/11057988).

**

### UPDATE

**

This turned out to be a case of incorrectly setup `commandLine` field in the `Activity` definition and service not being able to handle this gracefully. OP had their `Activity` definition setup like so:

```json
"commandLine": [
  "[$(engine.path)/revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[MyFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[MyBundle].path)\"]"
],
```

The correct way to define this is:

```json
"commandLine": [
  "$(engine.path)/revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[MyFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[MyBundle].path)\""
],
```

The extra starting and closing square brackets inside the `commandLine` `string` definition caused the problem. The bad command line started with `[$(engine.path)/revitcoreconsole.exe` but should have been `$(engine.path)/revitcoreconsole.exe`.

The `Activity.commandLine` field by itself is an array (aka collection) of commands to be run on the worker. Each of those command line instruction strings need to be a valid command after the variables referenced in them are expanded.

That said, most Design Automation for Revit will likely need only one of these two definitions each with a single command line instruction. The difference is based on the fact whether there is an input file to be opened.

**Option 1** (Open file corresponding to input argument `MyFile`)

```json
"commandLine": [
  "$(engine.path)/revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[MyFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[MyBundle].path)\""
],
```

**Option 2** (No document to be opened)

```json
"commandLine": [
  "$(engine.path)/revitcoreconsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[MyBundle].path)\""
],
```